# VSCode's intellisense doesn't work after intellisense's auto-highlighting

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, ide, intellisense, text-editor

After using intellisense to auto-complete some code, it often highlights some argument place holder text/value.
But while its highlighted, the intellisense stops working.
I have to click the esc key to get out the highlighting to continue using intellisense.
(if any of you use the macbook with the touch bar, you know how much effort it is to press the esc key )

[image]
*The highlighting might be hard to see, but its there the whole time I am typing "con"*

Anyone know how get intellisense working without turning off the auto-highlighting feature?
(also anyone know the official/unofficial name of the highlighting feature?)

Comment: Does `Cmd+space` work better for you?  I can't actually replicate your issue in javascript - possibly the language extension completionProvider isn't set up nicely.

Comment: @Mark not exactly, it turns my keyboard to Japanese haha. For me, Ctrl + space was another option but still an extra key stroke combination. Though thanks to you suggesting it could be in the language extension settings I found the issue!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue was in VS Codes languages settings for Dart.
Changing the `snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions` setting to `false` will solve the issue.

can be global...

```
{
    "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
}
```

or language specific...

```
"[dart]": {
    "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
},
```